# Microsoft Project 2003 - How to do a "find" in non-expanded nodes?

Tags: find, find-and-replace, microsoft-project

I am using Microsoft Project 2003 find command.

When I choose ctrl+f and type a string to search for, MS Project only appears to search tree nodes that are expanded.

Is there a way to get MS Project to search across all fields, even those that are collapsed?

Failing that, is there a shortcut to expand ALL nodes in the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry - I have been messing around for a while for you and I cannot find anyway to search for collapsed tasks.

As for expanding all, you can click the `Show` dropdown and then choose `All Subtasks` which should expand them all.

[image]

You can also get to it via the menu bar - `Project > Outline > Show > All Subtasks`.

[image]

Comment: The limited search capability is one of MSProject's (many) annoyances.  Solution is to expand to all subtasks as shown above, then search.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to switch on Auto filter (Project -> Filter -> Auto filter).
If you switch it on Task name, you can set a custom filter with containing text, like in Excel.